# Calculate Cholesky Decomposition using Eigen

Tags: c++, linear-algebra, eigen

I'm trying to calculate the Cholesky factor of a matrix in C++ (for a given matrix P find L such that LL^T=P).  My objective is NOT to solve a linear system P*x=b, as such matrix decompositions are often used for, but to actually obtain the matrix L.  (I'm trying to calculate "sigma points" as is done in the unscented transform.)

The library [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/index.html) supposedly calculates Cholesky decompositions, but I can't figure out how to get it to give me the values in matrix L.  When I attempt the following lines of code

```
Eigen::MatrixXd P(3,3);
P << 6, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 7;
std::cout << P.llt().matrixL().col(0) << std::endl;
```

I get compiler error

```
error: ‘Eigen::internal::LLT_Traits<Eigen::Matrix<double, -0x00000000000000001, -0x00000000000000001>, 1>::MatrixL’ has no member named ‘col’
```

The [documentation](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1LLT.html) says that LLT.matrixL() returns type Traits::MatrixL.  What is that and how do I get the values of L?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can look up what the Trait is in the LLT.h header file. Its a [TriangularView](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1TriangularView.html) like the documentation says. The triangular view does not have a `col` member, so that is why you get the error. Copying the triangular view into a dense matrix like so:

```
Eigen::MatrixXd P(3,3);
P << 6, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 7;
Eigen::MatrixXd L( P.llt().matrixL() );
std::cout << L.col(0) << std::endl;
```

will get you what you want.